# Creating a javascript object with an optional key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, idioms

I'm looking for an idiomatic method of creating an object with an optional key, i.e. the shortest way of doing the following:

```
let obj = {a: 1}
if(condition)
    obj['b'] = 2
console.log(obj)
```

One way I've thought of is:

```
console.log({a: 1, ...(condition ? {b: 2} : {})})
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: You could also use, `Object.assign`. Like,  `let obj = {a: 1}
obj = Object.assign(obj, condition ? {b:1} : {})`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's more or less the same and a lot longer.

Comment: @simonzack yeah except spread syntax for objects is still just a proposal.

Comment: Is there a relationship between `condition` and the key  `'b'`?  Is there a particular nature to the object that could help inform the decision.  To me  the first version is perfectly readable.

Comment: @GantTheWanderer Not really. Indeed the first version is readable enough but I find myself doing this quite often in my code that a very short one would be nice.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Thanks, good find, the second answer helped!